# What's meaning of this? "nums[-1] = nums[n] = -∞"

Tags: list, algorithm

May I ask what this mean?

```
nums[-1] = nums[n] = -∞
```

I saw it in leetcode 162：https://leetcode.com/problems/find-peak-element/

Comment: A terrible way saying the first element of the array is greater than it's left neighbor (which doesn't exist) and the last element is always greater than it's right neighbor, which also doesn't exist, so you can assume them to be minus infinity/smallest value possible

Comment: Note that in any programming language, if this line has any meaning, then it will certainly be very different than the meaning intended by the author of this text. For instance, in most programming languages, `=` means assignment rather than equality; and in some languages, negative indices are used to index from the end of an array, so -1 would be the index of the last element.

Comment: @Stef, when you see pseudocode like `var = 1`, you simply infer that variable `var` was assigned to `1`. You don't dwell on that some languages have `var` as a reserved keyword, and some languages have `:=` as an assignment operator. That's meaningless.

Comment: @Aivean Not sure what your point is. In this case, the equal sign was specifically **not** assignment, so your inference would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First element of the array in most languages has index `0`. Last element has index `n-1`.

If you try to access element before the first, by calling `nums[-1]` you would naturally get an "out of bounds" error or a segfault. Same for the element after the last: `nums[n]`.

The author of the leetcode task suggests to "extend" the domain of the array indices in the following way:

```py
def nums_get(i):
  return -∞ if i == -1 or i == len(nums) else nums[i]
```